# AWS NAT vs AWS IGW vs AWS Router

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, gateway, amazon-nat-gateway

As per this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/262093/220043), router and gateway are same devices, in terms of functionality.

In AWS world, we have [internet gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html),  [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) and  [router](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html)

Are these three not the same?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No they are not the same.

1. **Internet Gateway**

   - Routes traffic from instances with **Public IPs** to the Internet.
   - It simply forwards traffic between *Public IPs* in your VPC and *Public IPs* in the internet back and forth, mostly unchanged.
   - Gateways can sometimes be called *routers* but AWS doesn't use this term.
2. **NAT Gateway**

   - Routes traffic from instances with *only* **Private IPs** (i.e. *without Public IPs*) to the Internet.
   - It *translates* the *Private source IPs* of your instances to the NAT Gateway's *Public IP* - hence it's called NAT - **Network Address Translation**.
3. **VPN Gateway**

   - Routes traffic between *Private IPs* in your VPC and *Private IPs* in your **data-centre**.
   - It's not used to access Internet and doesn't change any addresses.
4. **VPC Peering**

   - Routes traffic between Private IPs of instances in **different VPCs**
   - It's not used to access Internet and doesn't change any addresses.
5. **Hosted router appliances**

   - Routing / firewalling software **running on EC2**, e.g. [Cisco CSR 1000](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00OCG4OAA),  [OpenVPN](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00MI40CAE) or similar gateways.
   - Used for special purposes, if you need it you probably know what you're doing.

Your link to "[router](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html)" actually links to **[Route Tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html)**

- *Route Table* is essentially a list of rules - IP address prefixes and their gateways.
- The rules are evaluated from the most specific to the least specific, i.e. the *best match* is used.
- Default route `0.0.0.0/0` covers all addresses in the whole internet.

  - In **Public VPC subnets** this *default route* usually points to **IGW**
  - In **Private VPC subnets** this *default route* usually points to **NAT GW**
- More specific routes (e.g. `10.20.30.0/24`) may point to **VPN GW** or **VPC Peering GW** or **Router appliance**.

Hope that answers the question :)

Comment: Really good answer. Something I'd like clarified: does the NAT Gateway allow port forwards? (or other features of a home NAT router) Do any of these act as a firewall? (I believe no--firewalling is handled at the instances via security groups)

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Nope, NAT GW can’t do port forwarding from outside. You can use **Network Load Balancer** to achieve the same though.

Comment: Such a nice answer. Well done!